# An unknown zero in my array list

Tags: java

Please see my code below, in the last two lines of my code that is `ArrayList<Float> minList = minsMap.get(minC);` and `minList.add(itemElement);`,  I am facing issue. In the first line when value of `minC` is zero that is `minC = 0` then in the second line zero is added to the list instead the value of `itemElement`. In itemElement i have no zero. Please help me figure out what's wrong with this code.

```
public class absol 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        float  item[] = {7,4,8,5,6,65,45,33,8,6,3,98};

        final float[][] arrayTwoD = {   {3.5f,  4.55f,  2.1f,   1.40f},
                                        {0.5f,  1.55f,  0.90f,  1.59f},
                                        {4.5f,  5.55f,  3.1f,   2.4f},
                                        {1.5f,  2.55f,  0.10f,  0.60f},
                                        {2.5f,  3.55f,  1.10f,  0.40f},
                                        {61.5f, 62.55f, 60.1f,  59.4f},
                                        {41.5f, 42.55f, 40.1f,  39.4f},
                                        {29.5f, 30.55f, 28.1f,  27.4f},
                                        {4.5f,  5.55f,  3.1f,   2.4f},
                                        {2.5f,  3.55f,  1.10f,  0.40f},
                                        {0.5f,  0.55f,  1.90f,  2.6f},
                                        {94.5f, 95.55f, 93.1f,  92.4f}, 
                                    };


        Map<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> minsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // Initializing Map
        for(int i=0; i<arrayTwoD[0].length; i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Float> minList =new ArrayList<>();
            minList.add(0.0f);
            minsMap.put(i, minList);
        }


        for(int row=0; row < arrayTwoD.length; row++)
        {
            float min = arrayTwoD[row][0];
            int minC = 0;
            float itemElement =0;

            for(int col=0; col < arrayTwoD[row].length; col++)
            {
                if(arrayTwoD[row][col] < min) 
                {       
                    min = arrayTwoD[row][col];

                    itemElement = item[row];
                    minC = col;
                }
            }

            ArrayList<Float> minList = minsMap.get(minC);
            minList.add(itemElement);

        }

//      for(int i= 0; i< minsMap.size(); i++)
//      {
//          System.out.print("\n\t Values in List "+i);
//          for(int j= 0; j< minsMap.get(i).size(); j++)
//          {
//              System.out.print("\t"+minsMap.get(i).get(j));   //////////////////////////////
//          }
//      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide an expected output? It may help speed up getting a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the reason why you get more zeros than expected is this condition:

```
if (arrayTwoD[row][col] < min) {...}
```

if the first item (`float min = arrayTwoD[row][0];`) is the min, the if block is not executed and you have intialised `float itemElement = 0;`...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
float itemElement =0;
```

with

```
float itemElement = item[minC];
```

You are initializing with 0, not the correct item value.